# For loop values to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, struct

I have a question. (See at the end)

Code:

```py
def bin_to_raw(file):
    header_len = 12
    field_names = ['time', 'count']
    for i in range(0, len(file), 12):
        data = struct.unpack('< q i', file[i:i + 12])
        for values in data:
            print(values)
    return entry_frame
```

Edit: **data is a tuple of two elements (time and count)**

My Output is:

```py
637727292756170000
-343
637727292756171501
-359
637727292756173001
-358
637727292756174502
-345
637727292756176002
-366
637727292756177503
-350
637727292756179004
-355
637727292756180504
-358
..........
```

Output of types:

```py
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
.....
```

**My Question now: How can I get all of this values in a dataframe?**

Like in this format:

| time | count |
| --- | --- |
| 637727292756170000 | -343 |
| 637727292756171501 | -359 |
| ..... | ...... |

**Thanks a lot in Advance guys!**

Comment: `test` is `data`?

Comment: Show us where you declared `test`

Comment: sorry guys, i edited it :) @Corralien
--> Test is data

Comment: @0xRyN edited in the code, sorry! :)

Comment: data is a tuple of 2 elements --> time and count

Comment: why not reading the data into a numpy array using [`fromfile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) and then make a df from this array?

Comment: Please provide a snippet of the actual data file.

Comment: @Stef the "raw" data is already a pd.df --> but i want as output also a dataframe, the output are only different tuples..

Answer (score 0):

You can define a dictionary, store the values with `time` as a key and `count` as the value and convert it to a dataframe when returning like this:

```
def bin_to_raw(file):
    data_dict = {}
    header_len = 12
    field_names = ['time', 'count']
    for i in range(0, len(file), 12):
        data = struct.unpack('< q i', file[i:i + 12])
        #assuming data[0] = time value and data[1] = count value
        data_dict[data[0]] = data[1]
    return pd.DataFrame(data_dict.items(), columns=['time', 'count'])
```

The reason for using a dictionary is that it is faster than appending rows to the dataframe each time in the for loop.